# How to generate an SSL certificate in Python3

Tags: ssl, python-3.x

I need to generate self-signed certs for using HTTPS on a single-user web server. It's important that the user is able to set the certificate up however they like. They need to be able to set the Common Name and so on.

In an pure Python3 environment, how do you generate a self-signed certificate?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To create self-signed certificate you could use openssl as it is available on all major OSes.

```
$ openssl req -new -x509 -key privkey.pem -out cert.pem -days 1095
```

Try the above code in python and see if it works.